# C# CultureInfo NumberFormat NumberDecimalSeparator Problem

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I want to change NumberDecimalSeparator of my application from "." to "/". it works when i show float numbers in my textbox. but integer types are not shown at all.

I modify thread's culture to get application-wide formatting. my code is like this:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa-IR", true);
ci.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

result:

3.14 => "3/14"
100  => ""

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

I just create such testing console application but have got a output like this:

```
Input next value:
3.14
3/14
Input next value:
100
100
```

My code was:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);            
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Console.WriteLine("Input next value:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            while (input != "e")
            {
                double dblInput = double.Parse(input);
                CultureInfo ci2 = new CultureInfo("fa-IR", true);
                ci2.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
                ci2.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci2;

                Console.WriteLine(dblInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Input next value:");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is here something not applicabale to your question?